# Don't enter on if and don't pass through

Tags: c, linux, fifo

I have an if statement:

```
printf("name");
if((fp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
}
printf("name2");//Debug propose
while(fgets(mensagem,250,fp)!=NULL){
    printf("%s",mensagem);
}

fclose(fp);
```

For some reason , `name2` is never printed but `name` is printed , `path` is a Fifo:

```
mknod(path, S_IFIFO|0666, 0);
```

Comment: Two general suggestions: 1. use `puts()` to print string literals 2. flush the `stdout`.

Comment: And two lines like `fp = fopen(path, "r");` then `if (fp == NULL)...` is a *LOT* more readable.  As well as a lot less bug-prone.  You're not writing a textbook - saving a line isn't going to save your publisher $0.0001 per copy printed.

Comment: fp = fopen(path, "r"); have same result before if stops

Comment: Are you sure that `mknod` doesn't return errors? What is the content of `path`?

Comment: when outputting to stdout, to avoid the output being 'hung' in the stdout buffer, end each format string with `\n` (best) or follow each call to `printf()` with a call to `fflush(stdout);`  (not so good but still workable)

Comment: Note: when there is characters in the stdout buffer, a 'input' statement will cause the stdout buffer to be flushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the FIFO man page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

That is, unless you open it explicitly in nonblocking mode.

So, I would expect your process to be hanging in the `fopen()` call until someone opens the fifo for writing as well.